# Determine if the function $f(x)$ is integrable in $[0,1]$

Tags: calculus, limits

Determine if the function $f(x)$ is integrable in $[0,1]$

$$\displaystyle f( x) =\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x^{2}} & x >0\\
0 & x=0
\end{cases}$$

---

***Attempt:***

Let's check the limits of each side $0^+$ to show that $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is not bounded.

$$\displaystyle \lim _{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{1}{x^{2}} =\infty $$

Therefore, the function is not bounded when $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}$
, and is not integrable in $[0,1]$

In addition, there is a well-known theorem:

> If $f$ is a continuous function except for the finite number of unconsciously points $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is integrable.

Which contradicts the attempt.

Comment: The second theorem is only true if $f$ is bounded.

Comment: Read the well known theorem again. It requires $f$ to be bounded. Also, what is a "unconscious" point?

Comment: The function is not defined for $x<0$, so it makes no sense to talk about $\lim_{x\to 0^-} f(x)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theorem that you have in mind states that a *bounded* function from an interval $[a,b]$ into $\Bbb R$ is Riemann-integrable if and only if its set of points of discontinuity has Lebesgue measure $0$. So, there is no contradiction here. Besides, note that the concept of Riemann-integrable function is defined only for bounded functions anyway. My guess is that you had *improper* integrals in mind.

Besides, the assertion $\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac1{x^2}=\infty$ is irrelevant here, since the domain of $f$ is $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

The theorem if $f$ is a continuous function except on finitely many points then $f$ integrable is only true if $f$ is bounded .

The function $1/x^2$ is clearly unbounded so the theorem does not apply .